# How to force UIInterfaceOrientation?

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation

I am writing an app and run into two problems. I have been searching the web all night without success and wonder if anyone here can help.

1. When the application starts, I want it to default to Landscape mode and Detect whether it is in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft or UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight. I have created the UI in landscape mode in the .xib file. However, when I check self.interfaceOrientation it always returns UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft regardless of whether the home button is on the left or right in the iPad simulator.
2. When the user rotates the iPad between the two landscape orientation, I want the view the change. To illustrate with a simplified example, if it is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, I want to write 1 on the left side of the screen and 2 on the right side of the screen. In UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight, write 2 on the left side of the screen and 1 on the right side of the screen. Which method in iOS can tell me whenever the user rotates the device?

Thanks very much in advance.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

1. Where are you checking that? If you're doing it in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` or in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` then it's likely the interface orientation isn't set properly yet. Wait until `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` to check that.
2. Take a look at `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in your view controller. You need to return `YES` to supported orientations so in your case you want to return `YES` if `interfaceOrientation` is landscape (there's a helper function for checking landscape vs portrait by the way). Also look at `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` which tells you when the user has rotated.

   - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: 1. I checked it in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation by adding an NSLog statement. It's probably not the best method as sometimes it seems it never return 'yes' from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation after I added the NSLog. 2. Thanks and I will check the link you provide.